# SQL Server 2008 cannot connect to Database Engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't know how to do this. I opened my SQL Server and connected using Windows Authentication at 10am. Until now, it does not go to the "Explorer".

I checked the services. The SQL Server Browser is running as well as the SQL Server Service. I restarted the service, but this did not solve the problem.

What should I do?

Below is the screen shot of the error.
[image]

(note the Server name has bee removed intentionally, I am actually using a server name)

Here's regarding the services I mentioned earlier
[image]

Comment: shouldn't you specify a server name? localhost at least most probably.. or named instance if one is used

Comment: As mentioned below, I removed it in the image for security reasons.

Comment: I' confused - the screenshot does not show any error. It is connecting right now. Type the message into Google and follow the instructions. Much quicker answer that even SO provides.

Comment: You need to clarify: does it time out or not? Also please clarify is this a SQL Server installed locally or are you connecting to a remote server over the network? Is it the default instance or a named instance (contains a \\) Please edit your original question and add the info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you can't see any databases listed in the Object Explorer? If so, click 'Connect' and choose to connect to a Database Engine. This should then list the server in that list.

Or if it is there, maybe it just needs to be expanded?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the situation. That's the situation of my SQL Server at 6:54pm. It's really taking too long.

Comment: You haven't specified which server you want to connect to. Enter the name of the machine where the SQL Server is. If it's on the same machine you can use either localhost or just . (the full stop mark)

Once you've done that the Connect button should be enabled and you can click it.

Comment: I removed it in the picture for security reasons. So I'm connecting to a server and it's 6:57pm right now.

Comment: Oh I see. So you have the server name, and then you click Connect, and then what happens? Nothing? After a while you should get an error message, even if it's just to tell you that it's timed out. Can you post that message?

Comment: If it's local instance try to use (local) in server name, if not check dns server ie ping it by name. Try to use sa login/password, sometimes server is in state that allow only sa to connect, but you should get an error.

Comment: It seems that my machine shut down. Will give you an update on Monday.

Comment: Guys, it's 9:38am and no error message was displayed. What could be the problem?

Comment: So.. you fill out the Server Name, the Connect button is enabled; you click it. Then what? Nothing at all? Even after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that connection was working earlier? Maybe you could try to access server using dedicated administrator connection? Here is a brief description:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068.aspx

Another thing worth checking are protocols used for communication with server (shared mem, named pipes, tcp/ip, via) - check whether they haven't been disabled.

Maybe there is something also with your domain? If you use domain credentials, then maybe SQL Server has problems communicating with it.

If connection was not working before, then check whether you have approved windows authentication access.

Comment: I tried when I disabled the communication with the server and I got this error. The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with service-specific error The data is invalid..

Comment: @Musikero31: Have you searched logs, whether there is any information connected to your problem (at least standard windows logs available from event viewer, sql server log)?

Comment: No message is thrown in the Event Logs. I don't know where to locate the sql server logs.

Comment: And this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/03/21/how-to-verify-path-for-sql-server-error-log-files.aspx

Comment: You could try to post (or move) your question here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ Maybe someone will come up with new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL server configuration manager, there is an item called SQL server network configuration, under protocols, I selected the properties of the TCP/IP protocol. There is a tab "IP Addresses" there, and at the bottom of the list is an entry called IPAll. In my case the TCP port was empty. I entered the SQL standard port 1433 in there and I was able to connect.

This should work!!!

Regards
Mohammed

Answer (score 0):

The server name should be PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS or PCNAME\MSSQLSERVER